# Actionscript 2 - variable keeps getting reset after clicking a button?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I only have one frame in my flash activity. In the actions layer, it creates a variable called

```
var placedOnCard1 = '';
```

There are 2 blue circles, 1 red card and a submit button. When you drag the circle and place it on card 1, placedOnCard1 = 'circleOne'. If you drag the second circle and place it on card 1, placedOnCard1 = 'circleTwo'. This works.

Now, the code for the submit button is

```
on (release) {
    trace('when clicking submit, card on cardOnAns1 is ' + placedOnCard1);
}
```

Whenever I drag either of the circles on the card, the variable placedOnCard1 changes correctly but when I click submit, placedOnCard1 goes back to being just '' (an empty string). Why is this and how do I stop this from happening?

Note that in my actions layer, I also tried doing this

```
trace('placedOnCard1 gets reset');
placedOnCard1 = '';
```

and it only traced 'placedOnCard1 gets reset' once, it didn't reset the variable after I clicked submit so why does placedOnCard1 become an empty string after I click submit even though I'm not even switching frames? The whole flash activity is just on one frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it looks for `placedOnCard1`  in button' inner scope. Try :

```
on (release) {
    trace('when clicking submit, card on cardOnAns1 is ' + _root.placedOnCard1);
}
```